# Sprout Forms CC

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

Does anybody know if it's possible to CC people on Sprout Forms notifications? I know I can add multiple email addresses to the notify field, but ideally, I would like to CC someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprout Forms (for Craft 3) supports CC and BCC options as well as the option to send to recipients as individual emails (where each recipient just sees that they received an email) or as a single email (where each recipient can see the other users who the email was sent to or CC'd.

---

Legacy Answer:

At the time of this posting, there is no way to CC a person using Sprout Forms. It's on our list to consider adding at some point.

With Sprout Email, you can set up multiple notifications so that one email is sent to one user and another is sent to another user.  This doesn't solve your goal of CCing a user either, but it would let you get the secondary email address you want to CC out of the primary email to: field.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I talked with my client yesterday and they were actually fine with being included in the to: field.

Comment: Any update on this? Is adding a CC/BCC still on the list to consider?

Comment: Hey @TrevorDavis, just updated the original answer. Still on the list, but back on the drawing board.

Comment: Sprout Forms now supports CC & BCC options.