# User and Admin email notifications

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I may be missing something really obvious in the docs - so sorry if I have - but is there a way to send both the user (sender) a notification email, and the admin a different notification email?

Something like what I want has been hinted at: [Sprout Forms CC](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11370/sprout-forms-cc)

I know I could set multiple email addresses in the notifications option: *Sprout Form > Forms > My Form > Notifications (tab) > Email Recipients (field)* but the issue I have is how can I dictate which template is used?

I'm happy to set/use the default options for the Admin email, if you could point me in the right direction for a custom user email option, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprout Forms supports multiple Notification Emails (as of Craft 3) and multiple Email Template. Sprout Forms also now supports CC and BCC functionality.

Create a new Notification Email on the `Sprout Forms->Notifications` tab. Each Notification Email has a setting for the Event that you would like to use to trigger it. You can select the "When a form entry is saved" event to trigger an email when a form submission is saved.

While there are numerous ways to trigger an email to both an admin and the user submitting a form, two common methods are:

1. Setup a single Notification Email and set the `To` field to the handle of a custom field that has the users email, such as: `{email}` and set the BCC field to your email address of the admin who you wish to receive it as well. You can separate multiple recipients using a comma-delimited list.
2. Setup two Notifications Emails and adjust the messages of each to each respective audience. You can create custom, company-branded Email Templates for the user-facing email. Impress them and set expectations for any follow-up communications. Send a workflow-oriented email to the admin, showing all data submitted in the form and linking to any next steps the admin may have to take after the email is received. The default `Basic Notification (Sprout Forms)` Email Template will loop through and display all values of the Form submission.

---

Legacy Answer:

In Craft 2, you are correct that Sprout Forms can send multiple notification emails to both admins and users, however the default Sprout Forms notification currently only supports a single template.

It's on our list to consider updating this default behavior. For now, your best options are:

1. Send the same email to both users and admins.
2. Add [Sprout Email](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email/) to the mix which integrates with Sprout Forms and allows you to customize as many emails and templates as you'd like and trigger them on the Event: *When a Sprout Form Entry is submitted*

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've opted for option 1 for now, which suits the client's needs. Cheers for getting back to me so quickly.

Comment: Hi @ben-parizek I am trying to do this with Sprout Forms 3.0.0
Does this mean I need to purchase Sprout email as well to send different emails to users and admins?

Comment: @TimPrint I've updated my answer to de-emphasize my comments about Sprout Email and focus on what Sprout Forms can do. You do not need to purchase a separate copy of Sprout Email. Sprout Forms Notifications allow you to create multiple notification emails, send to users and admins, and customize Email Templates for your project's branding or transactional email workflow needs.